# How to append a Qstring using "%" operand

Tags: c++, append, qstring

I am trying to `.append` my QString with two `double` values using the `%` operand. I saw the following example in the QString class reference documentation for using `arg` with double, but the example doesn't include appending the str:

```
double d = 12.34;
QString str = QString("delta: %1").arg(d);
```

here is my code. it does not include any run-time error but it doesn't place my doubles where the `%` operand is, instead it include my %1 and %2 as normal strings too:

```
double d1 = 0.5,d2 = 30.0
QString str  = "abc";
str.append("%1 def %2").arg(d1).arg(d2);
```

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
double d1 = 0.5,d2 = 30.0
QString str  = "abc";
str.append(QString("%1").arg(d1));
str.append(" def ");
str.append(QString("%1").arg(d2));
```

[EDITED] The point is, the "arg" is a method of a class QString and must be used with an instance of it. In your not-working example you don't do this.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now:

'str.append(QString("%1 def %2").arg(d1).arg(d2));'

may I ask why it is working now?

Comment: @duDE : thank you for your explanation, I always keep on making the same mistake as Rania-Boy, but thanks to your explanation, I will probably remember to do it correct the next time :-)

Answer (score 5):

Use this

```
str.append(QString("%1:%2").arg(d1, d2));
```

or

```
str.append(QString("%1:%2").arg(d1).arg(d2));
```